# Как проверить переменную int на инициализацию?

Tags: java, переменные, инициализация

Есть переменная, которая просто объявляется:

```
int a;
```

И есть необходимость проверить была ли она уже инициализирована. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Компилятор проверит и откажется компилировать программу, выдав ошибку. Самостоятельная проверка не имеет смысла и поэтому нет способа такой проверки.

Comment: @Sergey жаль, что нет :( спасибо

Comment: А зачем вам это понадобилось?

Comment: @СемёнШнурков, вы пишете: "жаль, что нет :("  --- если это у вас вызывает сожаление, то вы, скорее всего, чего-то не понимаете про переменные. Трудно представить ситуацию, где бы это понадобилось. Но если это не локальная переменная метода, а поле объекта, то она по умолчанию будет автоматически инициализирована в 0. При объявлении того и другого можно добавить инициализацию: `int a = 1234567;`,  и если это будет значение, которое не может быть присвоено в другом месте программы, то  потом можно проверить - если это значение сохранилось - значит, ничего не присваивалось.

Comment: @m.vokhm Скажу сразу, я пока только начал изучать java. До этого писал на php, и там были функции для этого, которые я часто юзал. Следовательно, у меня было много ситуаций где проверка на инициализацию действительно была нужна(может, конечно, дело во мне).
Присваивать какое-либо рандомное значение типа `int a = 1234567;`, а потом проверять его, по мне как-то костыльно, ведь есть какая-либо вероятность, что в будущем присвоится именно это значение. Спасибо за ответ, постараюсь вообще избегать эту проблему:)

Comment: @m.vokhm Java избавляет Вас от таких проверок и тем более от ошибок, как если бы Вы забыли выполнить такую проверку в php. Это очень строгий язык. Не то чтобы жаба была идеалом, но программируя на жабе либо вы научитесь правильно составлять программы (даже не на жаве), либо бросите жаву. Совсем жёстко говнокодить тут не получается. Ну то есть когда говнокодишь, тут это заметно сразу, причём самому.

Comment: @Sergey, вы, видимо, ошиблись адресом :)

Comment: @m.vokhm бывает

Answer (score 3):

Как я знаю, Java в отличии от языков С++ и ниже сам по себе не инициализирует переменные...

Допустим если в C++ написать: `int a;` и не инициализировать его, после компилирования и вывода на экран можно увидеть что твоя переменная была автоматически инициализирована определенным числом взятой из оперативной памяти.

Но в Java как я знаю этого нет.. И если вы попытаетесь использовать в условиях вашу не инициализированную переменную или объект, компилятор не скомпилирует ваш код, ну или выбросит NullPointerException... Поэтому чтоб будучи чтобы использовать ее в условиях и прочее, лучше заранее задать данной переменной определенную **константу** или **0** но при этом быть на **100%** уверенным что данная переменная **никогда** не присвоит вашу константу или же 0, после чего проверять была ли изменена переменная или нет...

Как-то вот так:

```
int a = -999;
//code
//Действия над переменной a
//code
if(a != -999){
    System.out.print("Твоя переменная была изменена!");
}
```

Comment: `Java в отличии от языков С++ и ниже сам по себе не инициализирует переменные` – инициализирует, но не все.

Comment: `int` по умолчанию будет инициализирован как 0, а `Integer` как null. Потому, что `int` - это простой тип, а `Integer` - класс.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov; @post_zeew  по умолчанию инициализируются только поля класса все остальное компилятор Вас заставит инициализировать! И даже `int` будет инициализирован вручную `int int = 0;`

Comment: @IgorKudryashov, Не всегда.

Comment: @Виктор, Это Вы к чему?

Comment: @post_zeew описал как и когда инициализируются переменные, вместо "инициализирует, но не все." и "Не всегда. "

Comment: @Виктор, Так а меня зачем упомянули? Я не спрашивал.

Comment: Это все конечно хорошо, но если я не уверен, что переменная не присвоит именно эту константу? Получается, что есть вероятность, что все сломается) Я уже понял, что нет стандартного способа, буду делать как-нибудь по другому, избегая этой проблемы. Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть только один вариант что переменная будет не инициализирована: Если это переменная объекта и она является полем класса. Тогда будет достаточно проверки на null. Примитивные же типы, если они поля класса, будут инициализированы по умолчанию. Если же переменная объявлена в коде, компилятор не даст Вам работать с ней пока вы ее не инициализируете, в большинстве случаев

Comment: В таком случае переменная будет инициализирована. `null` – это тоже инициализация.